# How to remove element "this" from list in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I remove the `<li>` with jQuery?

```js
function addTask(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var task = $("#todo").val();
  $(".taskList").append("<li>" + task + "<div class='deleteIcon'>x</div></li>");
  $("#todo").val("");
  $("li").click(complete);
  $(".deleteIcon").click(deleteItem);
}
$("form").submit(addTask);
$(".taskList").sortable();

function complete() {
  $(this).addClass("complete");
}

function deleteItem() {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bubblegum+Sans|Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

<h1>Write your tasks here</h1>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="todo" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<ol class="taskList">
</ol>




<script>
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by just calling the `deleteItem` `onclick(this)` function and add `this` to it.

You can use the `jQuery` function `.remove()` and `.parent()` to remove the actual `li` you clicked on

You can either use `this` onclick or `_this` as an args on the `deleteItem` function. Both will work fine.

You can read more about `.remove` [here](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and `.parent()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Run snippet below to see it in action.

```js
function addTask(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var task = $("#todo").val();
  $(".taskList").append("<li>" + task + "<div class='deleteIcon' onclick='deleteItem(this)'>X</div></li>");
  $("#todo").val("");
  $("li").click(complete);
  $(".deleteIcon").click(deleteItem);
}
$("form").submit(addTask);
$(".taskList").sortable();

function complete() {
  $(this).addClass("complete");
}

function deleteItem() {
  $(this).parent().remove()
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>To do list</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bubblegum+Sans|Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Write your tasks here</h1>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="todo" required>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <ol class="taskList">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

**Using .closest**

You can also do this using `.closest`

```js
function addTask(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var task = $("#todo").val();
  $(".taskList").append("<li>" + task + "<div class='deleteIcon' onclick='deleteItem(this)'>X</div></li>");
  $("#todo").val("");
  $("li").click(complete);
  $(".deleteIcon").click(deleteItem);
}
$("form").submit(addTask);
$(".taskList").sortable();

function complete() {
  $(this).addClass("complete");
}

function deleteItem() {
  $(this).closest('li').remove()
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>To do list</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bubblegum+Sans|Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Write your tasks here</h1>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="todo" required>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <ol class="taskList">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `_this` is the event object, not the element. `this` inside `deleteItem` is the element

Comment: Why did you add an inline `onclick` to the HTML? Remove that, then use `$(this).closest('li').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteItem(event){
  $(event.target).parent().remove()
}
```

Basically, every event handler function receives an Event object as it's parameter when called. More info on this can be found at at a resource like MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

The event has a property, "target", who's value is the DOM element that got clicked. We can wrap this with jquery so that we can use jquery functions on it.

if you'd rather rely on the this keyword like you did with the "complete" function.

```
function deleteItem() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

also works.